# Is std::vector.data() null-terminated on a vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, undefined-behavior

I am using a C library in my C++ application.
One of the functions needs a `null-terminated array of pointers`.

Since I am using C++, I am storing the elements of the array in a `std::vector`.

I would like to know if it's safe to simply call `data()` on my vector and pass the result to the library function.

Exemple :

```cpp
std::vector<struct A *> vec;

//library_function(struct A **array);
library_function(vec.data());
```

Of course, if I change the elements in the vector then the pointer returned by `data()` will be invalidated, but that is not an issue here (I can call the function again when updating the vector).

I am just afraid this might be undefined behavior, since I can't see *anywhere* mentioned that `data()` is terminated by a null pointer and not by random garbage.

The standard does say :

```
const T* data() const noexcept;

Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage.
The pointer is such that range [data(); data() + size()) is always a valid range
```

So there is a terminating element, but it doesn't say if that element is initialized and if it is, with what value.

Is it specified somewhere else that I missed?
Or do I have to allocate a raw array and null terminate it myself?

Comment: `data()` is not null terminated.

Comment: Where and how did you get the idea there's a terminating element?? No there isn't. It's preposterous to require one, the API you are using is insane.

Comment: @PasserBy For a C API I don't think it is so uncommon to terminate arrays of pointers with null pointers, see e.g. POSIX `environ` or `execve`.

Comment: There is no terminating element. Dereferencing `data() + size()` is undefined behaviour. The closing round bracket in your qoute of the standard mean, that the range is valid **excluding** `data() + size()`.

Comment: `[a, b)` is a half-open range; it includes `a`, but not `b`. (This is common maths notation.) All ranges in the C++ library are half-open.

Comment: Why can't you just pass `vec` to `library_function()` and have `vec.size()` (or *range-based* `for` loop), or the normal iterators `.begin()` and `.end()` available for iterating over the set elements? Or is `library_function()` a C function that is causing the issue?

Comment: Why would you need a "raw" array? What's preventing you from adding a null pointer to the vector?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin See the first sentence of the question `I am using a C library in my C++ application.`

Comment: I saw that, then the decision tree kicked in and after looking at possibilities and why none were looked at, it became clear `library_function()` was the C function that was causing all the fun.

Comment: @JakobStark oh right I didn't pay attention to the closing round bracket, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vector of pointers is null terminated if the last element of the vector is null. There is no extra null element after the last element (like there would be a null terminator character after the last element of a `std::string`). The last element of a vector isn't null automatically. If you need the last element to be null, then you must insert the null element.

Example:

```
std::vector<A>  vec_of_struct(size);
std::vector<A*> vec_of_ptrs;
vec_of_ptrs.reserve(size + 1);
std::ranges::copy(
    std::views::transform(
        vec_of_struct,
        [](A& a) { return &a; }
    ),
    std::back_inserter(vec_of_ptrs)
);
vec_of_ptrs.push_back(nullptr); // null terminator pointer
library_function(vec_of_ptrs.data()); // C function
```

Comment: Heck of a way to use a vector in the same manner you would use an array of pointers with a sentinel `NULL` in C. Seems like `.size()` or `.length()` would provide the same information in any scope without needing the explicitly set `nullptr`? Maybe not if it is some blended C/C++ setup. Nice answer here.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if you call a C library function, that is provided by someone else, you can't just ignore the api and pass a vector. If the api states, that it is expecting a NULL terminated array of pointers, that is what you have to pass it.

Comment: After going though the mental-gymnastics, it boiled down to `library_function()` being the C function that was causing the issue to begin with. The sentinel `NULL` would work fine there.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't think of simply inserting a null pointer 
Thanks !